# Automatically select front or back camera depending on which one can "see"

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, barcode, avcapturesession

I have an app that allows people to use a barcode to check into an event. The app can run on iPhone or iPad, but some people run it on an iPad in a kiosk.

Using the app on a handheld iPhone or iPad, it makes sense to default the avCaptureSession to the rear camera. However, I'd like my app to automatically select the front-facing camera if the rear camera cannot "see" (i.e iPad is installed in a kiosk, or device is in a case that blocks the rear camera.)

Does anyone know of a library or code snippet that would see all black and automatically switch cameras?

Comment: Not sure about accomplishing what you're asking, but you could just default to whatever camera was used last in your app. That way it would theoretically only need to be switched once.

Comment: I may end up doing that. But as a process-automation professional, I have a motto: "If the computer CAN do it, the computer SHOULD do it." I've come across a couple of motion-detection libraries. Perhaps they could work for my needs.

Comment: I think [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172116/getting-exposure-values-from-camera-on-iphone-os-4-0) may have my answer. Essentially, snap a photo, look at the EXIF to examine the exposure setting. If the camera's blocked, exposure should be maxed.